# Basic error with `putStrLn` in Haskell. VScode extension Haskelly

Tags: haskell, visual-studio-code, haskell-stack

```
main = do line <- getLine
        let line' = reverse line
        putStrLn $ "You said " ++ line' ++ " backwards!"
        putStrLn $ "Yes, you really said " ++ line ++ " backwards!"
```

Error:

```
$ stack runhaskell "c:\Users\FruitfulApproach\Desktop\Haskell\test.hs"

C:\Users\FruitfulApproach\Desktop\Haskell\test.hs:4:5: error:
    parse error on input `putStrLn'
  |
4 |     putStrLn $ "You said " ++ line' ++ " backwards!"
  |     ^^^^^^^^
```

I've also tried it with a single tab on the indented lines.

Here's my tabs -> spaces setting:

[image: tabs to spaces setting screenshot]

I've also tried restarting VSCode.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe your code is insufficiently indented. Try this:

```
main = do line <- getLine
          let line' = reverse line
          putStrLn $ "You said " ++ line' ++ " backwards!"
          putStrLn $ "Yes, you really said " ++ line ++ " backwards!"
```

Specifically, your lines following the `do` should be indented just as much as the thing that comes after it, namely `line <- getLine`.

Comment: Yes, that was it!  Works perfectly now :)  This would have taken all day to solve, lol.

Comment: The problem was that the `let`, as indented, wasn't part of the `do` block, but came after. The following `putStrLn` was then in a position where the `in` keyword was expected.